# How do i change a list to enum?

Tags: c#

I have a list element that I am using for cards. I cannot use this element and need to exchange it with enum. Is it possible? This is the code. The values added are fine but i just need to make it so that they could work in an enum element. I have tried exchanging the list code with just enum but it expectedly did not work. I do not know enough about this language and thus i have to ask for help no matter how simple the question might be. I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2019.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  //start screen
    List<Card> playercardList = new List<Card>()
    {
        new Card() { Value  = 0, Name = "null", Image = "null" }
    };

    List<Card> bankercardList = new List<Card>()
    {
        new Card() { Value  = 0, Name = "null", Image = "null" }
    };

    int playercardSum = 0;
    int bankercardSum = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    List<int> usedCards = new List<int>();
    List<PictureBox> bankerbox = new List<PictureBox>(); 
    List<PictureBox> playerbox = new List<PictureBox>();

    // card value and image
    #region creationof52carddeck
   
    List<Card> deck = new List<Card>()
        {
            #region spades

            new Card() { Value  = 2, Name = "Two Spades", Image = "2S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 3, Name = "Three Spades", Image = "3S.png"},
            new Card() { Value = 4, Name =  "Four Spades", Image = "4S.png"},
            new Card() { Value = 5, Name = "Five Spades", Image = "5S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 6, Name = "Six Spades", Image = "6S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 7, Name = "Seven Spades", Image = "7S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 8, Name = "Eight Spades", Image = "8S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 9, Name = "Nine Spades", Image = "9S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Ten Spades", Image = "10S.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Jack Spades", Image = "JS.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Queen Spades", Image = "QS.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 10, Name = "King Spades", Image = "KS.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 11, Name = "Ace Spades", Image = "AS.png" },

            #endregion

            #region diamonds

            new Card() { Value  = 2, Name = "Two Diamonds", Image = "2D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 3, Name = "Three Diamonds", Image = "3D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 4, Name =  "Four Diamonds", Image = "4D.png"},
            new Card() { Value = 5, Name = "Five Diamonds", Image = "5D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 6, Name = "Six Diamonds", Image = "6D.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 7, Name = "Seven Diamonds", Image = "7D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 8, Name = "Eight Diamonds", Image = "8D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 9, Name = "Nine Diamonds", Image = "9D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Ten Diamonds", Image = "10D.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Jack Diamonds", Image = "JD.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Queen Diamonds", Image = "QD.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 10, Name = "King Diamonds", Image = "KD.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 11, Name = "Ace Diamonds", Image = "AD.png" },

            #endregion

            #region clubs

            new Card() { Value  = 2, Name = "Two Clubs", Image = "2C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 3, Name = "Three Clubs", Image = "3C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 4, Name =  "Four Clubs", Image = "4C.png"},
            new Card() { Value = 5, Name = "Five Clubs", Image = "5C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 6, Name = "Six Clubs", Image = "6C.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 7, Name = "Seven Clubs", Image = "7C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 8, Name = "Eight Clubs", Image = "8C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 9, Name = "Nine Clubs", Image= "9C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Ten Clubs", Image = "10C.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Jack Clubs", Image = "JC.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Queen Clubs", Image = "QC.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 10, Name = "King Clubs", Image = "KC.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 11, Name = "Ace Clubs", Image = "AC.png" },

            #endregion

            #region hearts

            new Card() { Value  = 2, Name = "Two Hearts", Image = "2H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 3, Name = "Three Hearts", Image = "3H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 4, Name =  "Four Hearts", Image = "4H.png"},
            new Card() { Value = 5, Name = "Five Hearts", Image = "5H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 6, Name = "Six Hearts", Image = "6H.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 7, Name = "Seven Hearts", Image = "7H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 8, Name = "Eight Hearts", Image = "8H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 9, Name = "Nine Hearts", Image = "9H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Ten Hearts", Image = "10H.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Jack Hearts", Image = "JH.png" },
            new Card() { Value = 10, Name = "Queen Hearts", Image = "QH.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 10, Name = "King Hearts", Image = "KH.png" },
            new Card(){ Value = 11, Name = "Ace Hearts", Image = "AH.png" }

            #endregion
        };

    #endregion
```

Comment: Where's the enum? Did you declare any? And how is the `Card` class/structure defined?

Comment: There is no enum. I have a list that i want to convert to enum. It is defined as you see in the code. @41686d6564standsw.Palestine

Comment: No, your code doesn't show us how `Card` is defined. It only shows how you declare and initialize the _list of cards_. More importantly, you need to have an enum, to begin with. And what _exactly_ do you mean by "convert to enum"? Are you trying to convert the `List<Card>` to `List<SomeEnum>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try foreach like below example,

```
var dayNames = new List<string> {"Monday", "Tuesday ", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
var dayValues = new List<DayOfWeek>();

foreach (var dayName in dayNames)
 {
   var dayValue = (DayOfWeek) Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), dayName);
   dayValues.Add(dayValue);
 }
```